# Can you group multiple candlestick series next to each other in a highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts, gwt-highcharts

Is it possible to have multiple candlestick series on the same axis and have them grouped next to each other like columns? Right now,they render on top of each other if their y values are similar. I have tried the series options related to this( point padding, grouping ) and they do not work.

Comment: So you need to group two series or group points in each serie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add the option "dataGrouping" to the series this way:

`serie = {
    type: 'candlestick',
    name: 'test',
    data: seriesdata,
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true
    }
}`

For further information, check this: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping